# Laravel 5.3 : 2 same relationships for 2 same Tables

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

i need help for make something  : I have 2 table :

```
- Users
----------
id_user


 - Sports
----------
id_sport

title_sport
```

User can practice 1 or more sport.

User can search user who practice 1 or more sport.

Can you help me please for the model User?

Comment: It looks as a [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Please read the docs for more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thank you for your comment , i am agree with the many to many relationships but can have 2 same relation in my model?

Comment: You can use as many as relations in your model. But the question is why you need it and what is the use-case of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can i use something like this ?

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function pratice()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport');
    }
   public function search_user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport');
    }
}
```

with 2 pivots table.